# How can I group and get the median num in Spark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a dataframe like this

```
+------------+----------+
|         A  |    B     |
+------------+----------+
|aaaaaaaaaaaa|11        |
|aaaaaaaaaaaa|44        |
|bbbbbbbbbbbb|22        |
|aaaaaaaaaaaa|33        |
+------------+----------+
```

I want to get the median of the value of column B in each column A.

```
+------------+----------+
|         A  |    B     |
+------------+----------+
|aaaaaaaaaaaa|33        |
|bbbbbbbbbbbb|22        |
+------------+----------+
```

How can I do it? Thanks for answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UDF](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html), groupBy and [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@collect_list(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to achieve it. Here is code example in Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def median[T: Numeric](xs: IndexedSeq[T]): Double = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) 0.0
    else {
      // There is faster algorithms (O(N), n-th order statistics) for finding percentiles,
      // but let's go with this one for simplicity - O(NlogN)
      val sorted = xs.sorted
      if (sorted.length % 2 == 1) implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(sorted(sorted.length / 2))
      else {
        // [1, 2]
        val a = sorted(sorted.length / 2)
        val b = sorted(sorted.length / 2 - 1)
        implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(a, b)) / 2
      }
    }
}

/// .... 

// This is important to make `toDF` visible!
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val medianUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf[Double, IndexedSeq[Int]](median[Int])
val df: DataFrame = Seq(("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 11), ("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 44), ("bbbbbbbbbbbb", 22), ("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 33))
  .toDF("A", "B")
df.show()
//  +------------+---+
//  |           A|  B|
//  +------------+---+
//  |aaaaaaaaaaaa| 11|
//  |aaaaaaaaaaaa| 44|
//  |bbbbbbbbbbbb| 22|
//  |aaaaaaaaaaaa| 33|
//  +------------+---+

// Using UDF as aggregation function. Input for this UDF is indexed sequence - result from collect_list
df.groupBy(col("A"))
  .agg(medianUDF(collect_list(col("B"))).as("median"))
  .show()
//    +------------+------+
//    |           A|median|
//    +------------+------+
//    |bbbbbbbbbbbb|  22.0|
//    |aaaaaaaaaaaa|  33.0|
//    +------------+------+
```

Comment: but what if you have billions of rows for each group and using aggregation it will produce only two rows with all values in these array columns on which is called UDF? I wonder if it will work correctly in parallel

Comment: @chlebek, most probably Spark will be able to handle 1 billion integers (1*10^9*4 bytes ~ 4 Gbytes), but in bigger scale it will fail. One of the ways to do it - use [approxQuantile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0//api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions), but before you need to make sure that dataframe contains only values for that key

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to compute all the medians in parallel (approximately of course).

Let's start by collecting all the possible keys:

```scala
// generating data (BTW, please provide that code next time you ask a question)
val df = Seq(("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 11), ("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 44),
             ("bbbbbbbbbbbb", 22), ("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 33))
    .toDF("A", "B")

val cols = df.select("A").distinct.collect.map(_.getAs[String](0))
```

Let's say `cols` has size `N`.
One way to go at it would be to iterate over `cols` and compute the median via N separate jobs. Another answer provide the code for that.

Yet, it is possible to compute all the medians in parallel (and therefore just one job) using a pivot.

```scala
val precision = 1e-3
val medians = df
    // the index is artificial, it is just meant to treat each line individually
    .withColumn("index", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
    .groupBy("index")
    .pivot("A").agg(first('B))
    .stat.approxQuantile(cols, Array(0.5), precision)

val result = cols.indices.map(i => cols(i) -> medians(i)(0)).toMap
```

It may not be worth it with only a few keys be could be interesting if you have more.

**EDIT**
The first solution keeps one line per line in the original dataframe and will work, I think, all the time. In case you have many keys, it could be interesting to compute the index with a window like this.

```
.withColumn("index", row_number() over Window.partitionBy("A").orderBy("B"))
```

But do not use windows if you have millions of rows per key. It could be very slow or even crash your job.